# Jsoup when connecting via the link, I get errors

Tags: java, ssl, https

when connecting via the link "https://dev.bolshoi.ru/visit/buyingnew/", I get errors, there is no error with other links, tell me what to do?

follow the link, for example "https://ya.ru /", there are no errors, for some reason there are no problems with other links

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:589)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:848)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:818)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:346)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:331)
at com.loftschool.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
... 19 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
... 24 more
```

```
package com.loftschool;


import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://dev.bolshoi.ru/visit/buyingnew/").get();
        System.out.println(doc.toString());


    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to pass an auth token or something...

Comment: Your JRE does not have a security certificate for "https://dev.bolshoi.ru/visit/buyingnew". I think you should be able to download the certificate from the website through Chrome Web browser. Search the Internet for how to do this. Then you need to install the certificate into your JRE. Again, search the Internet to see how to do this.